# Reglas de Backpack for Laravel son ignoradas en Google Cloud

Tags: laravel-5, google-cloud-platform

Tengo un problema con los archivos de request de backpack. Todo trabaja muy bien de manera local, pero cuando el proyecto está en Google Cloud, en los formularios, ninguna alerta salta cuando guardo todo el formulario en blanco o con datos que no cumplen las reglas, y me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De manera local aparecen las alertas definidas por las reglas en los archivos request, de manera correcta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Junto con el campo marcado con rojo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todas las alertas trabajan de manera local y ya que están en Google Cloud se ven ignoradas.

Este es mi archivo Request:

```js
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'short_name' => 'required|min:5|max:70'
        ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'short_name.required' => 'El nombre corto es requerido',
        'short_name.min' => 'El nombre corto debe contener 5 caracteres como mínimo',
        'short_name.max' => 'El nombre corto debe contener 70 caracteres como máximo'
      ];
}
```

En el informe de errores de stackdriver aparece lo siguiente:

```html
PHP Notice: Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException: The given data was invalid. in /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php:130
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest->validateResolved (/srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php:130)
```

Comment: Ya los agregué, @Aprendiz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el archivo app.yaml tenía lo siguiente:

```html
SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
```

Solo bastó hacer el cambio a:

```html
  SESSION_DRIVER: database
```

Y las validaciones ya aparecen en Google Cloud, fue todo